# Как запретить POST-запросы к серверу?

Tags: nginx, post, ip

Необходимо запретить выполнять POST-запросы к серверу с любого ip-адреса кроме одного. 
Желательно бы сделать это используя ipfw. Но можно и любой другой вариант.

Подскажите какой нибудь вариант.

**Что есть:**
Выделенный сервер.
FreeBSD 8.2
IPFW
nginx 1.4.2 в качестве фронтенд веб-сервера.
Apache 2.2.25 в качестве бэкэнд веб-сервера.

П.С.
Возникла необходимость бороться с так называемым slow post флудом.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
location / {
  limit_except GET {
    allow 192.168.1.0/32;
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

Взято из [официальной документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except).

Comment: GET нужно заменить на POST.
Правильно?

Comment: Нет, там Вы перечисляете только разрешенные методы. Например:

limit_except GET PUT DELETE { ... }

Таким образом для location будут разрешены только методы GET PUT DELETE. Для остальных будут выполняться правила, описанные внутри фигурных скобок.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста.
Для каждого сайта прописан server {}, а внутри него location {}

Я так понимаю необходимо дописать location{} вот таким образом?

server {

  location {

  }

  location {

  }

  ... 

  location / {

    limit_except GET {

      allow 192.168.1.0/32;

      deny  all;}

  }

}

Спасибо.

Comment: Вам необходимо дописать в том location, к которому Вы хотите применить ограничения. Например:

server {
 #запретит все запросы кроме GET к адресу /comments
 location /comments {
    limit_except GET {
      allow 192.168.1.0/32;
      deny  all;
    }
  }
 #запретит все запросы кроме POST к адресу /users
 location /users {
    limit_except POST {
      allow 192.168.1.0/32;
      deny  all;
    }
  }
 #запретит все запросы кроме GET ко всему сайту 
 location / {
    limit_except GET {
      allow 192.168.1.0/32;
      deny  all;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Вот начало конфига nginx.conf

 include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.domain;
 client_max_body_size 32M;
 log_format isp '$bytes_sent $request_length';
 server {
  server_name mysite.ru www.mysite.ru;
  listen 158.141.218.135;
  disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
  set $root_path /home/tfox/data/www/mysite.ru;
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
   root $root_path;
   access_log /home/nginx-logs/tfox isp;
   access_log /home/httpd-logs/mysite.ru.access.log ;
   error_page 404 = @fallback;
  }

Comment: Его продолжение.

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://158.141.218.135:81;
   proxy_redirect http://158.141.218.135:81/ /;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

Comment: Его продолжение.

  location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
   proxy_pass http://158.141.218.135:81;
   proxy_redirect http://158.141.218.135:81/ /;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

Comment: Конец конфига

  location @fallback {
   proxy_pass http://158.141.218.135:81;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
  include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.inc;
 }

Comment: Хочу наложить ограничение только на POST, а все остальное можно. Но при проверке синтаксиса он ругается.
location / {
    limit_except GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, LOCK, UNLOCK, PATCH {
      allow 192.168.1.0/32;
      deny  all;
    }

    proxy_pass http://158.141.218.135:81;
    proxy_redirect http://158.141.218.135:81/ /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

Comment: Если хотите запретить все запросы кроме GET ко всему сайту, сделайте так:

    location / {
        limit_except GET {
          allow 192.168.1.0/32;
          deny  all;
        }
        proxy_pass http://158.141.218.135:81;
        proxy_redirect http://158.141.218.135:81/ /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

Но я бы порекомендовал сделать ограничения только к той части, на которую идет slow post флуд.