# Запретить входящие POST-запросы

Tags: nginx, post, vds

Здравствуйте. На сайте (VDS) есть скрипты, которые берут данные POST-ом. Объем данных иногда может быть очень большой.

Хочу закрыть данные скрипты от наружного вызова. В каталоге нужном добавляю htaccess с содержимым

```
<Limit POST>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from моя маска подсети.
</Limit>
```

В итоге, правильно срабатывает из вне, но если перейти на сайт и нажать кнопку вызова данной функции (обычный select с выбором категории), то скрипт выдает 403. Я так полагаю, что в таком случае скрипт срабатывает не от ip сайта, а от ip посетителя ?

Спасибо за подсказки...

Comment: Так а зачем гадать по ip, посмотрите в логах веб-сервера откуда приходит запрос.

Comment: мне не нужно анализировать откуда идет запрос, мне нужно исключить любой внешний запрос

Comment: "Я так полагаю, что в таком случае скрипт срабатывает не от ip сайта, а от ip посетителя ?" Так а работает он где, в браузере или на сервере?

Comment: ну в браузере получается . В данном случае, меня больше интересует, как правильно исключить входящие POST-запросы из вне,а не разбор моих слов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запретить POST-запросы к серверу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245505/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83)

Comment: А как связаны mginx и htaccess?

Comment: И разве 403 это не ожидаемое поведение, раз уж вы хотите «закрыть скрипты от наружного вызова»?